# Where can I find Documentation for CS:GO console commands?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I googled for `csgo console documentation` but I didn't get what I wanted. Namely, I want documentation for the console language used in CS:GO. I found this [link](http://www.gamerconfig.eu/commands/counter-strike-global-offensive/) but it seems really sloppy. Is there official documentation for this?

Background: I get terrible ping when playing and I wanted to investigate why. This is why I wanted get the documentation to read up on network related commands such as `mm_dedicated_max_ping` and `net_status` and `status`. I also want this documentation just for general learning also....

I would ask why my ping sucks 90% of the time but that question is just too broad as I don't have much domain knowledge about how the internet works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to network diagnosis on the programmatic level and would be a better fit for SuperUser.

Comment: @scenia I disagree. This question is related to CS:GO as it contains console commands for Counter-Strike: Global Offensive.

Comment: @Mave Just because a game offers a programming interface a question about that programming interface isn't suddenly gaming related. In this specific situation, there's a site on the SE that would be a better fit, namely SuperUser. Even there, though, it would have to be reworded so as not to ask for a software recommendation in the form of a language documentation. Either way, it's off-topic here.

Comment: Why would it be a better fit there? That's insane. `mm_dedicated_max_ping` is in no way related to SuperUser, or anything else. It's Source specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [Valve developer wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_CS:GO_Cvars) has a list of all CS:GO console variables and descriptions of what they represent, including `mm_dedicated_search_maxping` and `net_status`.